# delayPressIn, delayPressOut, and delayLongPress disable touchableopacity onPress in react-native 0.62.2?

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchableopacity, onpress

I just updated a react native project from rn 0.61.5 to rn 0.62.2. Things are mostly fine except that the onPress on my `<TouchableOpacity>` doesn't respond if I have `delayPressIn`, `delayPressOut`, or `delayLongPress` in that same touchable opacity.

Getting rid of them is not ideal because I was using them to avoid triggering onPress for touchable opacities in a flatlist on scroll.

Looking in the most recent documentation for react native `delayPressIn`, `delayPressOut`, and `delayLongPress` are no longer listed on the documentation for touchable opacity or touchable hightlight. They are listed in the documentation for `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, but this doesn't fit my needs.

This is an issue regardless of whether I'm using just one, or more than one in combination.

For example:

```
<TouchableOpacity
//  delayPressIn={5}
//  delayPressOut={5}
//  delayLongPress={5}
    accessible={!this.state.menuOpen}
    onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('OneAlertScreen', {userId: userId})
    }} 
    title="Alert Details"
    key={item.alertNumber}
    style={styles.myCardStyle}
>
 
  ..........stuff inside my touchable opacity

</TouchableOpacity>
```

works, but if I uncomment any of those it won't. It doesn't throw an error - just fails silently.

Has anyone found a way around this? Thanks